# JMS RPC without temporary queues

Tags: java, spring, jms, rpc

In our application, we use an standalone ActiveMQ 5.7.0 between our frontend and backend. 
The frontend is connected through tcp (its on the same machine as ActiveMQ) and the backend is connected
via https over a proxy server (thats the only way we can communicate out of the backend).

We implemented some synchronous services by means of springs JmsInvokerServiceExporter. Now from time to time we are getting the following error in the frontend:

```
org.springframework.remoting.RemoteAccessException: Could not access JMS invoker queue [queue://schufaFeedback.QUEUE]; nested exception is org.apache.activem
q.ConnectionClosedException: The connection is already closed
        at org.springframework.jms.remoting.JmsInvokerClientInterceptor.convertJmsInvokerAccessException(JmsInvokerClientInterceptor.java:431)
        at org.springframework.jms.remoting.JmsInvokerClientInterceptor.invoke(JmsInvokerClientInterceptor.java:204)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.getSchufaFeedback(Unknown Source)
        at com.xxx.xxx.web.springmvc.controller.MyFormController.addCredits(MyFormController.java:109)
        at com.xxx.xxx.web.springmvc.controller.MyFormController.submitConsent(MyFormController.java:102)
        at com.xxx.xxx.web.springmvc.controller.MyFormController$$FastClassByCGLIB$$3517c773.invoke(<generated>)
        at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:689)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:80)
        at com.xxx.xxx.web.springmvc.aspects.StepAccessAspect.checkAcess(StepAccessAspect.java:33)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor117.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:65)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:161)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:80)
        at com.xxx.xxx.web.springmvc.aspects.AuthenticationAspect.authenticateControllerAccess(AuthenticationAspect.java:28)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor62.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)        
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:465)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
        at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
        at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:769)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:698)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:891)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.apache.activemq.ConnectionClosedException: The connection is already closed
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.checkClosed(ActiveMQConnection.java:1462)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.checkClosedOrFailed(ActiveMQConnection.java:1449)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.deleteTempDestination(ActiveMQConnection.java:2050)
        at org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTempDestination.delete(ActiveMQTempDestination.java:52)
        at org.springframework.jms.remoting.JmsInvokerClientInterceptor.doExecuteRequest(JmsInvokerClientInterceptor.java:372)
        at org.springframework.jms.remoting.JmsInvokerClientInterceptor.executeRequest(JmsInvokerClientInterceptor.java:251)
        at org.springframework.jms.remoting.JmsInvokerClientInterceptor.invoke(JmsInvokerClientInterceptor.java:201)
        ... 75 more
```

I think this happens, because the proxy is killing the connection from time to time and therefore the temporary queue used by 
Spring Remoting is useless (it always happens in "org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.deleteTempDestination").

To make these service calls more reliable we want to avoid the use of temporary queues and use static reply queues (or topics). I did not find a
solution to do this with Spring Remoting capabilities.

Solutions I found:

Spring integration - Outbound Gateway: you can specify a reply destination, but there is no connection to a interface.

Apache Camel Bean Integration - I'am not sure this is the right approach.

1. Could you give me any advise how to solve this without implementig the JMS logic by myself for every service method call ? I think the spring remoting approach is very comfortable since you just have to configurate the interface and implementation.
2. Do you know why these "Connection is already closed" exceptions occure ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override

```
org.springframework.jms.remoting.JmsInvokerClientInterceptor.doExecuteRequest
```

and

```
org.springframework.jms.remoting.JmsInvokerServiceExporter.writeRemoteInvocationResult
```

to use correlation id instead of temporary queue/topic and use them as standard spring remoting service.

Comment: thanks, I thought about this too, furthermore we even don't have to overwrite the ServiceExporter because spring already sets either the JMSCorrelationId (if set) or the JMSMessageId of the request as the JMSCorrelationId of the response.It Works fine !

Comment: At the end I also extended the JmsInvokerServiceExporter to set the deliverymode of the response queue to non persistent, to prevent messages getting stuck in case of timeouts.